# Applying djikstra on changing weights of an undirected graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, shortest-path

How to find the shortest path from 1 to n if the weights keeps changing every kth distance travelled?

given the number of vecrtices, edges and k. we need to find the shortest path from 1 to n.
after every kth weight added to the path. we have to wait k seconds to move again (hence the weight increase by k, but not in all cases).

If we hit the kth weight while traveling, the change will be seen later.
While travelling if we **hit every kth value**(meaning 4,8,so on), the remainder of the k time will only be waited. eg: k=4 graph : 1 2 6(u v w), 2 3 4. we travel from 1->2 but while travelling we have 4, so we wait 4 seconds (but we travel 6- so 2 seconds we are already waiting). thus we only wait 2 more seconds making total weight as 6+2=8 then we travel again from 2->3(since it's the last, we dont worry about waiting).

I tried to modify djikstra but It isn't correct.

```
int djikstra(int s,int n,int x,int k)
{
if(s==x) return 0;
for(int i=0;i<MAX;i++) d[i]=INF;

int temp=0;

priority_queue<pii,vector<pii>,greater<pii> > q;

q.push(pii(0,s));
int u,c,v,w;
d[s]=0;
while(!q.empty())
{
    c=q.top().first;
    u=q.top().second;
    q.pop();

    if(d[u]<c) continue;
    if(u==x)
        {return d[u];}

        for(int i=0;i<g[u].size();i++)
        {
            v=g[u][i].first;
            w=g[u][i].second;

            if(d[u]%k==0) temp=0;
            else temp=k-(d[u]%k);

            if(v!=x)
                {

            // cout<<temp<<"\n";
                    if(w<=k)
                    {
                        int we=w;
                        if(temp!=0)
                        {   

                            if(temp<=we)
                                {   we-=temp;
                                    w+=k-(we%k);
                                    temp=0;
                                }
                            else
                            {
                                temp-=w;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if(w%k==0)
                            {
                                w+=k;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                temp=k-(we%k);
                            }
                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        int wei=w;
                        wei-=temp;

                            if((wei/k)%2!=0)
                            {
                                w+=k-(wei%k);
                                temp=0;

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if(wei%k==0) temp=0;
                                else temp=k-(wei%k);
                            } 
                    }

                }

            if(d[v] > d[u]+w)
                {
                    d[v]=d[u]+w;
                    q.push(pii(d[v],v));

                }
        }
}

return -1;

}
```

Sample TC:

**Inp:**
5(n-no of vertices )
4 (k - kth values) 
6 (m- no of edges) 
1 2 3 (m lines defining undirected edges and weights)
1 3 4
2 3 3
3 4 2
4 5 2
3 5 4

**Outp:**
12

Explanantion:

1->3 ( 8 (4 weight + 4 wait) )
3->5 (4)
8+4=12.

Comment: It seems that you are using `weight` and `wait` interchangeably. Do the weights on the graph represent time as well as the "fine" of `k`?

Comment: What's the bound on `k`? If `k` is quite small then you can create `k` copies of your graph with different wait times (an edge of weight `k` could result in waiting any amount of time afterward) and then run normal Dijkstra

Comment: @shapiroyaacov, Basically weight here means the time, sorry for not clearly mentioning that. So basically every k second I have to wait k second before moving. Thus, if I arrive at some node at kth second(could be k,2k,3k,,,nk) I have to add k to the weight(or cost) of the node.

Comment: @pkpnd , I don't get it. how would making k copies help ? The question is to find the shortest path. But every kth second(k,2k,...) I have to wait k seconds before moving again. So add k to the already given weight If arrived at that time. But, If while travelling I hit the kth value I don't stop. I just wait the remainder of it, or none If the weight covers k seconds.